# Winsound slow down python program

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, pyaudio, winsound

I want to play a beep sound when there's a face show on webcam. The program works, but it slows down when I use winsound.Beep(). Is there any other way where I can play a sound like an alarm sound when someone's face shows up without lagging?
Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
import cv2
import random
import winsound

trained_face = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    success_read, frame1 = webcam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    face_coordinates = trained_face.detectMultiScale(gray)
    print(face_coordinates)
    if len(face_coordinates) > 0:
        winsound.Beep(500, 200)
        for (x, y, w, h) in face_coordinates:
            cv2.rectangle(frame1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(random.randrange(128, 256), random.randrange(128, 256), random.randrange(128, 256)), 2)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
            break
    cv2.imshow('Face Detector', frame1)
```

Comment: Where is it lagging?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. The problem has been solved by using threading.